# Accepting id in index.php CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can I accept id in index.php of base controller in CodeIgniter? I want to achieve `http://localhost/1234` instead of creating a method `user` another class like `account` ? Where the url becomes `http://localhost/account/user/1234`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way it's change the file route and set the rule with the id you want.

However, Why do you wanna do that? If you do that dont advantage the MVC of CI. I think.